# Rename multiple files, both UPPER to lower and lower to UPPER

Tags: bash, tr

I want to rename multiple files by 'UPPER to lower, lower to UPPER' rules.
ex) fiSH → FIsh, AmErIcA → aMeRiCa

I know how to simply replace all upper cases to lower cases. For example,

```
result='echo $name | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]''
```

But not how to replace all upper cases to lower cases and at the same time lower cases to upper cases.

Answer (score 1):

With `tr`:

```
result=$(echo 'fiSH' | tr 'A-Za-z' 'a-zA-Z')
```

Output to variable result:

```
FIsh
```